# Is there a proof by induction that $e^{i \theta} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, alternative-proof

A friend of mine says that for every theorem there exists a proof by induction that shows it true. However I cannot think of how could there be a proof by induction of Euler's famous identity: $$e^{i \theta} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$

Was my friend wrong by stating that or is there an actual proof by induction for that theorem? If the proof exists, please state it in your answer.

Comment: the induction works only in $\mathbb N $ which is countable and where each subset has a smallest member.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima False. It works for $\Bbb Z$. At least an induction proof with a small bit more will show this holds for $\theta\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Might depend on the starting point - namely, what are the three functions that appear in the identity - however, even if present, an inductive argument appears to be the point of least concern to me.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt It will still reduce to induction on $\mathbb{N}$, so basically that's it.

Comment: No but you could prove by induction that $e^{in\theta} = \cos(n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)$.

Comment: Actually, I get the feeling one can prove this holds for $\theta\in\Bbb Q$ using induction and trig identities alone. May require De'Moivre's theorem.

Comment: I suppose one could induct on $n$ in the Taylor polynomials of degree $n$ of both sides, but you'd also have to prove both sides converge to get out of the ring of formal power series and into actual functions.

Comment: Your friend is simply wrong.  Many inexperienced students attempt to prove everything by induction, even when it is unhelpful (or worse yet, counterproductive).

Comment: @gammatester Why would it contradict Gödel's incompleteness theorem?  A true statement need not have a proof, but a *theorem* is provable by definition.

Comment: Induction inherently can prove that a statement is true only on countable set. You could in theory use transfinite induction on any well-ordered set, but to effectively build inductive proof, you would first need to construct well-order and not only know its existence from axiom of choice.

Comment: all the complicated "stuff" in computer science can be reproduces using only Nand Gates, and the Nand Gate is very basic and simple gate, so i think his friend give an analogue in the Math world, also i think i saw a mathematician says that online (not sure) may be Numberphile or something close.